# How to get a list of all Animation Presets in an After Effects script

Tags: extendscript, after-effects, preset

I am looking for something like `app.effects` that returns all the Animation presets instead of the effects available. A way to get the install directory would also work.

Thanks !

Comment: Have you read the docs? ae-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/

Comment: Yes, and I found nothing. If anyone is interested I ended up doing it by looping the Presets folder and saving all the .ffx files and their path in an Array.